# Right-clicking doesn't always work

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, mathjax

When I right-click on the subject line of a question, I normally get a menu on which one item is "Open link in new tab".  But when the subject consists only of mathematical notation in MathJax, that doesn't work.

Comment: Workaround - middle/scroll click, to open in a new tab?

Comment: Also - this is true if you right click on _any_ portion of the title that is rendered mathjax.

Comment: Isn't this a classic [tag:status-bydesign] then, @Oded?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - more a matter of different features coming together to produce unexpected results. On the one hand, I'd expect a title to let you right click to open in a new tab, but then again, I'd expect mathjax to override the right click for rendered mathjax. Can't say that right clicking linked mathjax has defined behavior... or what the behavior should be...

Comment: @Oded but MathJax is an external tool used by Stack Exchange, so isn't this the same like for example transparent images that lose transparency when resized by imgur?

Comment: @Shadow - sure, to an extent. Not saying we are fixing it, just that the behavior is undefined ;)

Comment: See also [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex) on meta.math.

Answer (score 4):

MathJax has a hidden menu that allows you to control whether it produces the contextual menu or not.  You can enable this menu and use it to turn off the MathJax contextual menu if you wish.

To do so, open your browsers console (on the Mac this is usually done via command-option-C, but it depends on your browser; I'm not sure of the sequence for Windows and Linux).  In the console command line, type

```
MathJax.Menu.showContext(true);
```

and press RETURN.  You may also be able to do this by entering

```
javascript:MathJax.Menu.showContext(true);
```

in the URL type-in area, though some browsers restrict your ability to enter javascript URLs.

Now when you right-click or CTRL-click on an expression typeset by MathJax, the MathJax contextual menu will include a new sub-menu in the Math Settings Menu with the name "Contextual Menu".  It has two options: "MathJax" and "Browser".  Select "Browser".  This will mean that MathJax will not intercept the contextual menu, and the bowser will handle all clicks on typeset math as it does everything else.

If you want to get the MathJax menu after having done this, ALT-click (with the left button) on the typeset math to get the MathJax menu.

This setting is "sticky", so you can set it and have it retained for a year.  If you want to change back, either clear the MathJax cookie, or go through the `MathJax.Menu.showContext()` process again and select MathJax for the contextual menu option.

Answer (score 1):

MathJax is overriding the right click over elements it renders to show its own menu:

> [image]

That's how it works, and I don't think it should be any different for titles. As Oded [kindly advised](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245854/right-clicking-doesnt-always-work#comment804594_245854), you can simply middle click those links to open them in a new tab.